# Failed to Run AVD on AndroidStudio 2.1.2 Win7

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm new to Android, i have downloaded Android studio 2.1.2 and SDK. After reading references from google i wrote HelloWorld application, which can run on my phone.

But due to certain reasons i have to run **AVD** in AndroidStudio to execute my application. but is shows following error

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. /dev/kvm is not found.
>
> Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux
>   distro has working KVM module.

Following things i have done so far.

- Installation of HAXM manually.
- Enabled Virtualization from BIOS.
- Some of the references on stackoverflow suggested to uncheck Hyper-V
  option in Turn on off windows feature. (i have found nothing like
  hyper-V there)

I'm running **Windows 7**

I'm just stuck here. any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I have read that Dell Optiplex760 does not support virtualization.

but i can run VirtualBox on my machine. moreover i have seen Virtualization option in BIOS. Also Secureable shows that my system supports Virtualization.
[image]

Comment: If you are running Windows, why are there references to a KVM and Linux devices?

Comment: lolz android does this.

Comment: Okay then.. Umm, if you are sure you enabled (and saved) the BIOS setting, then I'd simply recommend using Genymotion, which doesn't require HAXM.

Comment: well let me give it a try.
and as far as i have seen on google, most of the people refer that if your machine does not support virtualization then AndroidStudio wont be able to run AVD

Comment: For the most part, that's correct for any virtualization tool like VMware or VirtualBox. Intel HAXM is the only crucial piece for the default AVD images.

Answer (score 0):

First, reboot you system, press the hot key to enter the BIOS.
[enter BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j61lI.jpg)

Second, enable the Inter(R) Virtualization Technology and save.
[enable VT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeCmr.jpg)

Third, start up your computer, enter CMD, input "sc query intelhaxm" to check the state.
[CMD command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLWo1.png)

Forth, start up your AVD, if error happens like that. Go next step.
[error tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0oUb.png)

Finally, go into your SDK directory, reintall the intellhaxm-android.exe again, then launch the AVD Monitor.
[reinstall haxm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re6SM.png)

I hope it works.